Spring Boot Admin Server custom notifications
How can I set up the Spring Boot Admin Server so that I can notify different users for different applications ? So far I can only notify the same users for status changes of all registered apps. But I want to notify e.g. user-1 for app-1 and user-1 and user-2 for app-2.
Is that possible, how do I do that?

Spring Boot Admin does not have explicit support for this use case, but you can still achieve your goal by manually configuring multiple notifiers of the same type but with different filters.
If you're using the Slack notifier, it might look something like this:
@Bean
public FilteringNotifier slackApp1Notifier(InstanceRepository repository, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    SlackNotifier slackNotifier = new SlackNotifier(repository, restTemplate);
    slackNotifier.setChannel("team1");
    // ... set all necessary properties

    FilteringNotifier filteringNotifier = new FilteringNotifier(slackNotifier, repository);
    filteringNotifier.addFilter(new NotificationFilter() {

        @Override
        public String getId() {
            return "team 1 filter";
        }

        @Override
        public boolean filter(InstanceEvent event, Instance instance) {
            return instance.getTags().getValues().containsKey("team")
                    && instance.getTags().getValues().get("team").equals("1");
        }
    });

    return filteringNotifier;
}

Also see the documentation about filtering notifications.
